# Appearance side of the div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to create a sidebar to death like this on this site http://gabrieleromanato.com/

Pressing the 'email icon in fact, it has the' effect I want.
I have little knowledge of jquery so I can not reach the 'goal.

I hope some of you can help me

Thanks in advance to all

Comment: It seems to be using a regular slide. As you want to rip-off the website layout, start by checking its source for javascript libraries and stylesheets in use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say your div which will show up on click has a width 300px. Your div css must contain two property atleast,

```
.div1 {
  position:fixed;
  top: 5%; // Use whatever you want
  width: 300px;
  left: -300px; // The width of your div, may have to change slightly based on your design.
}
```

now clicking on any icon say id icon1

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#icon1").click(function () {
       var left = parseInt($(".div1").css('left')) < 0 ? 0 : '-300px';

       $(".div1").animate({left: left }, 1000);
   });
});
```

This may help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/W2MfR/)

I've used .animate() to toggle the width of the boxes.

HTML:

```
<div id="box">
    <div id="opener">Opener</div>
    <div id="message">This is the message</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#box {
    position:fixed;
    top: 20px;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
}
#opener {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #000;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#message {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #f00;
    width: 160px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#box").css("width", "40px");
    $("#message").css("width", "0px");

    var show = 0;

    $("#opener").click(function () {
        if (show === 0) {
            $("#box").animate({
                width: '200px'
            });
            $("#message").animate({
                width: '160px'
            });
            show = 1;
        } else {
            $("#box").animate({
                width: '40px'
            });
            $("#message").animate({
                width: '0px'
            });
            show = 0;
        }
    });
});
```

You can any time generalize the jQuery so that you dont need to use hard coded values.